# Magento2.3: How to move sku above product title?

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, products, sku

I want to move the `sku` above the `product title`. But the problem I'm facing is that I can see two of the sku's in the product page(one is under product title and another is parallel to price). Please anyone tell me how to move the `sku` at above product title.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep below code inside xml file body tag in your xml file,

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title.top"/>
```

Note: Then you have to run Basic Command

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:f
```